# In Python how can I change the values in a list to meet certain criteria

Tags: python

In Python, I have several lists that look like variations of:

```
[X,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,X,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
[X,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,X,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
[0,X,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,X,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
```

The X can fall anywhere. There are criteria where I put an X, but it's not important for this example.  The numbers are always contiguous around/through the X.

I need to renumber these lists to meet a certain criteria - once there is an X, the numbers need to reset to zero.  Each X == a reset.  Each X needs to become a zero, and counting resumes from there to the next X.  Results I'd want:

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Seems like a list comprehension of some type or a generator could help me here, but I can't get it right.

I'm new and learning - your patience and kindness are appreciated.  :-)

EDIT: I'm getting pummeled with downvotes, like I've reposted on reddit or something.  I want to be a good citizen - what is getting me down arrows?  I didn't show code?  Unclear question?  Help me be better.  Thanks!

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far!

Comment: Is this input a string or a real list?

Comment: Also, what happens if the numbers after the X are not contiguous?

Comment: Do the lists always start with an x?

Comment: Edited to answer some of the questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the existing values don't matter this would work

```
def fixList(inputList, splitChar='X'):
    outputList = inputList[:]
    x = None 
    for i in xrange(len(outputList)):
        if outputList[i] == splitChar:
            outputList[i] = x = 0 
        elif x is None:
            continue 
        else:
            outputList[i] = x 
            x += 1
    return outputList
```

eg

```
>>> a = ['X',1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'X',11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
>>> fixList(a)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> b = ['y',1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,'y',12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
>>> fixList(b, splitChar='y')
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

EDIT: fixed to account for the instances where list does not start with either X or 0,1,2,...

Comment: This seems right.  Let me test and I'll give you the answer mark.  Thank you SOOOO much.  From the looks of this, I should feel dumb and ashamed to not have produced this myself.  :-/  Thanks again.

Comment: I think your edit quit replacing the X characters, and now starts the renumber after the X.  Running your test, I now get:  ['X',1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'X',11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]

Answer (score -3):

Using the string `'X'` as `X` and `the_list` as list:

```
 [0 if i == 'X' else i for i in the_list]
```

This will return the filtered list.

Comment: ... but it doesn't rebase the following numbers.